# CSS Date Ribbon in the wrong place

Tags: css

I just downloaded a CSS layout for date ribbon heading my posts. The problem is that when the post message is too little, the next ribbon gets in the wrong place. If the message is big enough, the ribbon stay in the right place (below the previous ribbon). The CSS code is:

```css
#newsmain{
        background: #f9f9f9;
        font-family: Georgia, "Times", "Times New Roman", serif;
        color: #999;
      }

.ribbon {
   margin: 0.25em 1em 1em 0;
   background: #fff;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   color: #f9f9f9;
 }
 .ribbon .top,
 .ribbon .middle {
   background: #833;
   padding: 0.1em 0.2em;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
   text-align: center;
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px #d9d9d9;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px #d9d9d9;
   box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px #d9d9d9;
 }
 .ribbon .middle { border: 0; }
 .ribbon .tail {
   height: 0.5em; width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -0.5em;
   left: 0;
   overflow: hidden; 
 }
 .ribbon .tail .right,
 .ribbon .tail .left {
   position: absolute; height: 1em; width: 100%;
   background: #833;
   bottom: 0.5em;
   -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -20deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   -o-transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   -ms-transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
 }
 .ribbon .tail .right {
   -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 20deg);
   -moz-transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   -o-transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   -ms-transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
   transform: skew(-0deg, -20deg);
 }
```

The HTML code for testing the problem is:

```
<div class="ribbon">
                <div class="top">May</div>
                <div class="middle">28</div>
                <div class="tail">
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <p id="newsmain" align="justify"> Little Message</p>

<div class="ribbon">
                <div class="top">May</div>
                <div class="middle">28</div>
                <div class="tail">
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <p id="newsmain" align="justify"> Large Message so the ribbon below are in the right place...............................................................................................................</p>

<div class="ribbon">
                <div class="top">May</div>
                <div class="middle">28</div>
                <div class="tail">
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <p id="newsmain" align="justify"> This ribbon is in the right place, like the ribbon above should be.</p>
```

I hope some of you guys (experts in the CSS field :D) can help-me, because I'm beginner.
Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what layout you are looking for but using the CSS [clear](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) property:

```
clear: left;
```

Worked when I added it to `.ribbon`.

```
.ribbon {
   margin: 0.25em 1em 1em 0;
   background: #fff;
   float: left;
   clear: left;
   position: relative;
   color: #f9f9f9;
 }
```

In addition: you may want to wrap your "Ribbon" and message with another div to keep them in the same overall box.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the fast answer :))

Comment: My pleasure, you asked your question well.